# How can I create this lead of helix cut in CAD?

Tags: cad, technical-drawing

In this blueprint: http://library.centerofthewest.org/digital/collection/WRAC/id/2703/rec/8894

How can I create this Head of helix cut?
[image]

I'm having trouble in determining the position of the plane and axis to generate the helix.

Comment: In parametric design, this generally involves making a spiraling helix geometry and then sweeping a cross section with it as a path

Comment: I would like to know where the cross section must be positioned at and which direction the helix should follow (X, Y, Z) and where is the Axis of the helix positioned. I think with this I would be able to do this cut.
I could not grasp this from the blueprint.

Comment: @Abel would you be able to help me in determining the above?

Comment: Position of helix does not matter as much as you might think.  Place it at a known point on your sketch plane for convenience- the one where you draw this cross section that is pictured